# what does arg_scope actually do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am a beginner in neural nets and TensorFlow, and I am trying to understand the role of [`arg_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/arg_scope).

It seems to me that it is a way to put together a dictionary of "things you want to do" to a certain layer with certain variables. Please correct me if I am wrong. How would you explain exactly what it is for, to a beginner?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When defining convolution layers, you may always use the same padding type and the same initializer, and maybe even the same convolution size. For you pooling, maybe you are also always using the same `2x2` pooling size. And so on.

`arg_scope`  is a way to avoid repeating providing the same arguments over and over again to the same layer types.

Examples from the [source documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py#L20):

> Example of how to use `tf.contrib.framework.arg_scope`:
>
> ```
> from third_party.tensorflow.contrib.layers.python import layers
>   arg_scope = tf.contrib.framework.arg_scope
>   with arg_scope([layers.conv2d], padding='SAME',
>                  initializer=layers.variance_scaling_initializer(),
>                  regularizer=layers.l2_regularizer(0.05)):
>     net = layers.conv2d(inputs, 64, [11, 11], 4, padding='VALID', scope='conv1')
>     net = layers.conv2d(net, 256, [5, 5], scope='conv2')
> ```
>
> The first call to `conv2d` will behave as follows:
>
> ```
>    layers.conv2d(inputs, 64, [11, 11], 4, padding='VALID',
>                   initializer=layers.variance_scaling_initializer(),
>                   regularizer=layers.l2_regularizer(0.05), scope='conv1')
> ```
>
> The second call to `conv2d` will also use the `arg_scope`'s default for padding:
>
> ```
>   layers.conv2d(inputs, 256, [5, 5], padding='SAME',
>                   initializer=layers.variance_scaling_initializer(),
>                   regularizer=layers.l2_regularizer(0.05), scope='conv2')
> ```
>
> Example of how to reuse an `arg_scope`:
>
> ```
> with arg_scope([layers.conv2d], padding='SAME',
>                  initializer=layers.variance_scaling_initializer(),
>                  regularizer=layers.l2_regularizer(0.05)) as sc:
>     net = layers.conv2d(net, 256, [5, 5], scope='conv1')
>     ....
>   with arg_scope(sc):
>     net = layers.conv2d(net, 256, [5, 5], scope='conv2')
> ```